# lookup certain time & date range as input parameter and then extract multiple patterns from each block of text

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to figure out a logic where we can pass time & date range as input parameter that run it against log file like below and then extract matching patterns from each block of text between blank lines:

Here's a sample content in a log file:

```
# 10/Oct/2017:11:14:12 -0400; conn=-1; op=59
dn: dc=capitalone,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: ds-sync-state
ds-sync-state: 0000015b51d7bf33057e00000002
ds-sync-state: 0000015b53b701d30f0c00000003
ds-sync-state: 0000015b51d655e11a0c00000005

# 11/Oct/2017:10:40:29 -0400; conn=-1; op=44
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
replace: ds-sync-generation-id
ds-sync-generation-id: 8408

# 11/Oct/2017:10:40:30 -0400; conn=-1; op=59
dn: cn=admin data
changetype: modify
replace: ds-sync-state
ds-sync-state: 0000015b50e62ee409b700000002
ds-sync-state: 0000015b4a174d3f217500000002
ds-sync-state: 0000015b4ed4fcfb23a500000008
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to do. Is that sample, a single log file or multiple log files? What data do you want to extract? Are there many log files with the same format? Should `11/Oct/2017:10:40:30` be treated differently to `11/Oct/2017:10:40:29`? Please expand your question for clarity.

Comment: There are multiple logs starting with same name (e.g. access_1, access_2). Yes, the sample is from a single log. Based on the date & time range we pass it needs to grep below attributes from the block of text under found date & time. Would like to pass the range in this way: "--start 11/Oct/2017:10:40:29 --end 11/Oct/2017:10:41:00":

Grep for following attributes:
dn:
changetype:
replace:

Comment: Your comment response is still not very clear. For example, are the `--start` and `--end` values "fuzzy" or "exact" for what is in the log files? Using your example (in the comment) and the sample log file data in the question, no records would be matched (exact) OR the last two would be matched (fuzzy).

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution:

**`lookup_by_daterange.awk`** script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function get_ts(dt, ts){ 
    gsub("/"," ",dt); 
    sub(":"," ", dt);
    cmd="date -d \""dt"\" +%s"; 
    while(cmd | getline t) ts=t; 
    close(cmd); 
    return ts 
}
BEGIN {
    from = get_ts(from);  # `from` datetime
    to = get_ts(to);    # `to` datetime
}
/^# [0-9]{2}\//{ 
    ts = get_ts($2); 
    if (ts >= from && ts <= to) { 
        f=1; n=NR+3 
    } 
}
f && NR<=n { 
    print 
}
NR==n { 
    print "" 
}
```

---

Usage:

```
awk -v from="11/Oct/2017:10:40:29" -v to="11/Oct/2017:10:41:00" -f lookup_by_daterange.awk logfile
```

The output:

```
# 11/Oct/2017:10:40:29 -0400; conn=-1; op=44
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
replace: ds-sync-generation-id

# 11/Oct/2017:10:40:30 -0400; conn=-1; op=59
dn: cn=admin data
changetype: modify
replace: ds-sync-state
```

Comment: Thanks bunch Roman... the script you wrote works like a champ... this captures the date and next three lines... is it possible to provide what parameter to return instead. For instance sometimes I only need one of the attributes like; ***"replace: "*** to return.

Comment: @Riz, to print only `replace: ...` lines - replace the line `f && NR<=n {` with `f && NR==n {`. That's all